# How to show list of main colours not all

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, enumeration

I want to give the user the chance of choosing a colour for the foreground. So I populate a combobox with

```
 foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(Colors).GetProperties())
      cmbStrokeColour.Items.Add(info.Name);
```

but that has 2 problems for it has way too many items:

1. it takes too long to be populated
2. it's confusing for the user

Is there a way to list ONLY the main colours and not all.
So now the problem is define main colours. I'd say it's a subset of that list. Well not only RED GREEN BLUE but not 141 items as in the list above.

Thanks for your help

Comment: As you already mentioned, it´s aproblem what you mean by "main-color". Specify this before you ask for a programmatic solution. Only if you clearified this you may add an implementazion based on Linqs `Where`-statement for instance.

Comment: What does "main colors" mean to you and how would you categorize/identify them? Also, can't you use the Take() extension from Linq?

Comment: Do you mean primary and secondary colours as red, blue, green, yellow, magenta, cyan? What about black and white? Even grey?

Comment: This is the problem. In WinForm I recall different colour sets: sytem colours, web colours etc... I thought that here there was something similar too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve all your problems by using the [Color Picker](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ColorPicker&referringTitle=Home) controlfrom the [WPF Toolkit Extended](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) toolkit.

It allows you to use a combobox with color choices that the user can select:

[image]

Or even use a color palete:

[image]

You can use this by referencing the namespace in your view:

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

And using it as a standard control:

```
<toolkit:ColorPicker Name="ClrPcker_Background" SelectedColorChanged="ClrPcker_Background_SelectedColorChanged"/>
```

And in your code behind:

```
private void ClrPcker_Background_SelectedColorChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Color> e)
{
    TextBox.Text = "#" + ClrPcker_Background.SelectedColor.R.ToString() + ClrPcker_Background.SelectedColor.G.ToString() + ClrPcker_Background.SelectedColor.B.ToString();
}
```

It evens allows you to select which colors are available for the user, how to sort them out  and more.

Comment: Fine that's a great solution and easy to implement too. But just for the sake of knowledge. Is there only ONE 141 element list? No other subsets as I said in my previous comment?

Comment: As far as I know, the is no existence or ways to differentate enums for web colors, desktop colors, and the like in WPF by default.